# Report Builder returning "Expression expected" on a textbox

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm confused, how is this not an expression? I get the error in the title using the expression below as a placeholder for a textbox.

```
=IF(COUNT(Fields!item.Value, "FGInputTest")=0,"Item and lot combination do not exist", First(Fields!item.Value, "FGInputTest"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSRS if statement is spelt 'Iif' not 'If'

Comment: No shame. Wood and trees; we all do it from time to time!!